# Getting a specific value from a table created in Code Behind

Tags: c#, jquery, webforms, code-behind

I am trying to retrieve a specific value from a table created at runtime in the code behind.
using jquery.

```
sb.Append("<tr><td>");
                sb.Append(prodCode);
                sb.Append("</td>");


                sb.Append("<td>");
                sb.Append("<input type='checkbox' name='chkBestSeller' value='Best Seller' style='font-size:x-small;'");
                sb.Append("<input type='hidden' name='prodCodeBestSeller' value='" + prodCode + "'");
                sb.Append("</td>");
Products.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
```

this is my jquery function.

```
$(document).on("click", "input[name='chkBestSeller']", function () {
var code = $(this).parent().find("input[name='prodCodeBestSeller']").val();
alert(code);

});
```

My feeling is that it should work but it brings back a value of 'undefined' instead.

How can i achieve retrieving the code value at the specific row

Comment: you are not closing your input's with `>` ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", "input[name='chkBestSeller']" ...
```

`this` refers to the element clicked on, i.e. `input[name='chkBestSeller']`.

In your case you can get the value of the hidden field with

```
$(this).next().val()
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$("input[name='chkBestSeller']").click( function () {
var code = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name='prodCodeBestSeller']").val();
alert(code);
});
```